# JavaScript, Thymeleaf and localizing text

Tags: javascript, html, thymeleaf

Our web page is built using **a lot** of JavaScript. I'm having trouble replacing text within generated markup with localized text. The JavaScript *is not* inline to the web page, but brought in with a  directive. Within the JavaScript is something like the following:

```
$("#Dynamic-Modal-Content").empty();     
$("#Dynamic-Modal-Content").append("<div class='dynamic_model' id='dynamic_id'>"+
    "<p>Done?</p></div>");
```

Within the web page is a

```
<div id="Dynamic-Modal-Content"></div>
```

I need to replace the "Done?" with localized text but can't figure out how. I tried the suggestion on http://blog.florentlim.com/how-to-write-javascript-including-thymeleaf/#comment-7224 but that didn't work.

This is a simplified version of the real code, but has the gist of the problem.

Any pointers from folks out in the big, wide world?

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 workarounds for this:

- You can use additional js files with the texts for each locale and pick the proper one with javascript on demand. Some ui widget libraries use this approach to some degree. However it has two major disadvantages. Javascript afaik can only resolve locale from the browser so you still need some communication -parameter passed- with server, if you keep a locale preference in session. Secondly and more important, you can't avoid splitting your i18n texts in different locations for each locale -one for server side and one for js.
- Use html5 data attributes. I believe using html5 data attributes is the cleanest way to communicate data between server side and js, not only for i18n.

For example your div becomes :

```
<div id="Dynamic-Modal-Content" th:attr="data-txt=#{label.done}"></div>
```

then with jQuery you can retrieve easily all html5 data attributes as if they are jQuery data:

```
$("#Dynamic-Modal-Content").data("txt");
```