# Spring messages in JavaScript and Thymeleaf

Tags: java, javascript, spring, internationalization, thymeleaf

I use Thymeleaf with Spring MVC 4.1.1 and I want to be able to re-use my Spring messages (with the user's automatically detected locale) for my JavaScript files. E.g. I want to do:

```
$('#fooTitle').text(messages['foo.title']);
```

...and #fooTitle would contain the value under `foo.title` for the user locale.

What would be the easiest way to do this? Note that I would like a JavaScript object ("dictionary") or another data structure which is easy to navigate.

Answer (score 2):

If not the easiest (but admittedly easy enough), the cleanest and most robust way is to use html5 data attributes to pass back-end data to js. This way, no matter if you move your javascript to external files, it still works.  Use some element as container (choose the most proper for your case) as a carrier of the thymeleaf back-end retrieved i18n values and then access them with jQuery

in html:

```
<div id="container" th:attr="data-foo-title-txt=#{foo.title}"></div>
```

in js:

```
$('#fooTitle').text($("#container").data("foo-title-txt"));
```

See also my older similar answer, (although the OP has not left any sign of life after that :) )
,
[JavaScript, Thymeleaf and localizing text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26724709/javascript-thymeleaf-and-localizing-text/26734536#26734536)

Comment: Thank you, that is indeed clever and would work, but in my particular case, it's simply not manageable!

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to include localization messages would be:

```
$('#fooTitle').text([[#{foo.title}]])
```

Comment: Thank you, but in this case, the JavaScript files are all split up and I'd just like to be able to access a JavaScript object ("dictionary") with all the messages.